# export an image in base64

Tags: php

I want to create an image in php having the data encoded in base64
Use the code: `file_put_contents('export/MyFile.png', base64_decode($img));`
I read on the browser, but 7483 should be a larger number.
if I open the image was created only half (the other half is transparent)
if the variable $img contains a short string, it works.
if it contains a string too long the image will be created only partially.
why?

PS: if I use

```
$img = base64_decode($img);
$fp = fopen("export/MyFile.png", "w");
fwrite($fp, $img);
fclose($fp);
```

I have the exact same problems

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents('export/MyFile.png', base64_decode($img));
```

Should be:

```
file_put_contents('export/MyFile.png', base64_encode($img));
```

If you want to encode the image, you can't use the decode function.

Comment: with this change if I try to view the image gives me an error.
But I think what is right because with a short string, export the image perfectly ... only when $img has a string of characters should not be long ...